# Bootstrap 3 - Use jQuery to remove class="disabled" from li which is dynamically loaded

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 and loading a common menu into all my html pages. Some of the elements in the menu are disabled and I want to enable them when I am on certain pages (i.e. no longer greyed out and no red circle when you hover over the selection). I have read and tried the following solutions.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="E1ActivitySelect.html">Activity - E1 Administration</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Activity - E1</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="disabled" id="liCamp"><a href="Camp.html">Camps</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hikes</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Major Events</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Pen Pals</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Include the common menu and amend
    $("#includedContent").load("Menu.html");

    // I have tried all these
    //  document.$("#liCamp").attr("disabled", false);
    //  document.$("#liCamp").attr("disabled", "");
    //  document.$("#liCamp").removeAttr("disabled");
    //  document.getElementById("liCamp").removeAttribute("class");
    //  document.getElementById("#liCamp").removeAttribute("class");
    //  document.$(".disabled").removeClass("disabled");
    document.$("#liCamp").removeClass("disabled");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) for the `.load()` method.

```
$("#includedContent").load("Menu.html", function(){
 $("#liCamp").removeClass("disabled");
});
```

Comment: This will make sure that the method `.removeClass()` is executed only after the `.load()` method has completed execution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#liCamp").removeClass('disabled');
```